# Java file reading for xml tag

Tags: java, java-io

i am reading a file in java i want data like firstname,lastname,nickname,marks from every nested student tag  in that file how to do in java file reading and writing concept below is my file

```
 <class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>kad</lastname>
      <nickname>dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="593">
      <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
      <lastname>singn</lastname>
      <nickname>jazz</nickname>
      <marks>90</marks>
      <student rollno="594">
         <firstname>jasvir</firstname>
         <lastname>singn</lastname>
         <nickname>jazz</nickname>
         <marks>90</marks>
      </student>
   </student>
</class>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1):

hope this will be helpful to you , i originally wrote this to extract the xml elements as java objects 
https://github.com/izi-SL/CSV-XML-Parser/tree/master/ParserProject/src/com/isuru/xmlreader

if this not suitable for your requirement try DOM or SAX parser